# AppleScript to pass dragged document to another application

Tags: applescript

Thanks to [help received on these fine pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578550/), my Mac has a little AppleScript to open a new session of Adobe Distiller.

```
do shell script "open -n -a " & quoted form of "Acrobat Distiller"
```

New question, asking for a small improvement to this. Can it be that if a .ps is dragged (or indeed, several are dragged) to the .app made by this .scpt, the new session of Distiller opens with that document (or those several documents)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the following script as an application. If you run the application, it will let you choose files to open in a new instance; if you drop files on it, it will open them all in a new instance:

```
on run
    set filesToOpen to choose file with multiple selections allowed
    set fileListString to createUnixFileString(filesToOpen)
    makeNewInstanceWithFiles(fileListString)
end run

on open droppedFiles
    set fileListString to createUnixFileString(droppedFiles)
    makeNewInstanceWithFiles(fileListString)
end open

on createUnixFileString(aList)
    set fileString to ""
    repeat with thisItem in aList
        set fileString to fileString & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of thisItem)
    end repeat
    return fileString
end createUnixFileString

on makeNewInstanceWithFiles(f)
    do shell script "open -n -a " & quoted form of "Acrobat Distiller" & f
end makeNewInstanceWithFiles
```

If you want each file opened in a separate instance, call `makeNewInstanceWithFiles` for each file (making sure to get the posix path and include a space as a delimiter) instead of calling the `createUnixFileString` handler.

Comment: Thank you. That’s magnificent.